# Addition of 2 numbers in shell script dynamically

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to take input from user and then based on that input either addition operation will be performed or subtraction will be performed. Choice 1 is for addition and 2 is for subtraction. The error I'm getting is this:

number.sh: line 12: d: command not found
(for addition line 12)

number.sh: line 17: d: command not found
(for subtraction line 17)

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter choice"
echo "enter 1 for addition"
echo "enter 2 for subtraction"
read a
echo "entered choice is" $a
echo "now enter 2 numbers"
if [ $a = 1]; then
read b
read c
d = `expr $b + $c`
echo "addition of 2 numbers is" $d
elif [ $a = 2]; then
read b
read c
d = `expr $b - $c`
echo "subtraction of 2 numbers is" $d
else
echo "enter valid choice"
fi
```

Comment: no space between assignments yo

Comment: didn't work. it says command not found. Could you modify it and post?

Comment: it worked but now I'm getting this: subtraction of the entered numbers is 1-2
and not the perfect answer

Comment: I assume you copy pasted your actual code here.

Comment: @sjsam I'm beginner trying to lean

Comment: Read the errors, they pretty much explain exactly what the problem is. Alternatively you can look at common bash mistakes or even use shellcheck.com to do all the work for you.

Comment: @123 sorry bro the domain is for sale. Any other website to check shell? Thanks.

Comment: @HarshitGarg http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra spaces around your assignments and missing spaces around your `[]` expressions. Here's a corrected version. Note that when you use two `read` calls, you need a newline in between when giving the input. That is, you have to type `1 <Enter> 2 <Enter> 3 <Enter>` on the command line to get a result of `5`.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter choice"
echo "enter 1 for addition"
echo "enter 2 for subtraction"
read a
echo "entered choice is" $a
echo "now enter 2 numbers"
if [ $a = 1 ]; then
read b
read c
d=`expr $b + $c`
echo "addition of 2 numbers is" $d
elif [ $a = 2 ]; then
read b
read c
d=`expr $b - $c`
echo "subtraction of 2 numbers is" $d
else
echo "enter valid choice"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

There should be no spaces around the `=` sign on line 12 and 17. Remove those spaces.
In bash, there should be no spaces around the assignment operator `=`.